# Include paths in PHP not working one directory up

Tags: php, unix, filesystems

Can anybody help with the last detail of my new system. I have hit a brick wall with some php code file references trying to include files and classes. I have a script that uses Pear Mail to send SMTP e-mails and it has been working fine for years in my public_html directory at my server service on a UNIX server. I have a copy of this script in a further directory, instructorapps, in my public_HTML directory and moving it up one level has broken it. From the errors it is obviously file references in the include path which is handled by the php code:

```
$path = "/home/thebrigh/php";
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
require_once ('../php/Mail.php');
```

This is the code that works in the public_html directory and I have tried many combinations of things to get it to work one level up.  get_include_path() returns .:/usr/lib/php:/home/thebrigh/php in the working file and .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/thebrigh/php in the non working one. It's the middle bit /usr/local/lib/php: that I guess is causing problems but I can't seem to get rid of it.

Many Thanks
Colin

Comment: @colin - Why not accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `require_once ('../../php/Mail.php');`

Comment: Many thanks Ed, it worked. Now I see the solution it's obvious. The supplier of my server service haven't been able to answer the support ticket yet.

Answer (score 0):

If `Mail.php` is in `/home/thebrigh/php`, just do `require_once "Mail.php"`

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately no success the returned file path is ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php" when the working one returns ".:/usr/lib/php:/home/thebrigh/php" Mail.php is a Pear class and I can't see it in home/thebrigh/php directory just a directory called Mail. But the working script seems to have no problem with this so I am ignoring it at the moment.